# Get the URL of the triggering build in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops

How can I access the URL of the triggering build in Azure Devops? I can access for example the buildId by using Build.TriggeredBy.BuildId. But I see no way on how to get the URL of the triggering build. If it's not directly available by predefined variables, what would be a good workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create the URL:

```
$(System.CollectionUri)/$(System.TeamProject)/_build/results?buildId=$(Build.TriggeredBy.BuildId)
```

Comment: That's what I am doing now. Thank you!